# Solving functional inequality

Tags: inequality

Can someone help me solve this inequality?

$$x^2-{\{x\}}^2\leq0$$

I tried solving it but I don't know how to go about inequalities dealing with fractional part. Please help.

Comment: Here's how I'd approach it. $-1 < \{x\} < 1$, so $\{x\}^2 < 1$, thus $x^2 < 1$. Now just check values of $x\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: Also think about the relationship between $x$ and $\{x\}$ when $x\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: There isn't a general agreement on definition of $\{x\}$ when $x$ is negative. What is your definition?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the given inequality is
$$(x-\{x\})(x+\{x\}) \leq 0.$$

Every real number $x=I+f$, where $I \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $0 \leq f <1$. Basically $I$ is the integer part (so $I=x-\{x\}$) and $f=\{x\}$ is the fractional part. So we want
$$I(I+2f) \leq 0.$$

Observe that if $x \in \Bbb{Z}$, i.e. $x=I$, then we have $I^2 \leq 0$, which means $\color{red}{x=0}$ is the only integer solution.

So let us assume $x \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Z}$, i.e. $x=I+f$ with $0 <f <1$. Then our inequality can be written as 
$$-2f \leq I \leq 0.$$

Since $-2<-2f<0$, we want $-2 < I \leq 0$. The only integer in this range are $I=-1,0$. So $x=-1+f$ or $x=f$, i.e. $\color{red}{x \in (-1,1)}$ is another solution. Observe that the integer solution $x=0$ is already covered in here. So $\color{blue}{x \in (-1,1)}$ is the solution set for this inequality.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped a lot.